# multiplication Table in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, math

[1][I write a simple program in dart to print multiplication table but the output was not I Except[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGOpe.png)

void main{

```
int num=10;

  for(var i=1;i<=10;++i){
   print('$num*$i=$num');
 }
}
```

this was my code

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, read the site [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to make a question. Also, show us your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to add the parenthesis in the main function which acted like a function declaration.

And you also missed to multiply the result of the multiplication by i.

The correct code is :

```
void main(){

int num=10;

  for(var i=1;i<=10;++i){
   print('$num*$i=${num*i}');
 }
}
```

instead of this:

```
void main{

int num=10;

  for(var i=1;i<=10;++i){
   print('$num*$i=$num');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer

```
var num = 10;
  for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    print("$num * $i = ${num * i}");
  }
```

any other ways to print multiplication table in dart using for loop

Answer (score 0):

```
void main()
{
 int num =20;
 for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
  {
    print("num* $i = ${num*2}");
  }
 }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Output is `num* 1 = 40`, `num* 2 = 40`, etc. Are you trying to generate algebra problems or something?